# Situating a Figure of the Goddess Uma in a Bedroom

Tags: gods, belief

Would it be considered culturally appropriate, from either a Hindu or Nepalese perspective, to situate a figure of the Goddess Uma in a bedroom or would this be considered taboo?

Comment: Every entity has certain energies associated with it, think of having kitchen or store room within the bedroom....does that make sense??? No, so common sense says either don't have it or if you really want to have it follow the rules and regulations properly.

Comment: @Just_Do_It as per which rules?

Comment: If you are going through Bhakti Yoga perspective then you can abandon all other rules (sarva dharmaan parityejjya...). So out of love for mother you can keep. Can't you keep photo of your mother everywhere? Will mother be angry? No, she shall see your love. But if you are going through other perspectives like applying mantras in photo, tantric rituals, or doing for specific purpose then you must follow all rules strictly.. because in this aspect you are seeing first deity then only mother... but in Bhakti yoga perspective you see mother then only deity...

Comment: Gods photos are not recommended to be kept in bedrooms whr husband and wife spends the night .. The people who spoke such lines and the people who lived around his time must hv also followed such rules... @Tejaswee

Comment: @rickross _"whr husband and wife spends the night"_ Then what about those people who made God's tattoo on body. Moreover I heard people who use to wear Tulsi mala (to please Lord Vishnu) they never wear off Tulsi mala in throughout their life, even while spending alone time with wife/hustband or while going to the washroom. So your theory doesn't seems application in every case.

Comment: Usually malas (Rudraksha specially) are to be taken off while going to bed at night .. I take it off (as instructed) before going to bed and thn wear it again the next day morning.. Not sure wht the rules are for wearing Tulasi Mala.. @Rishabh

Comment: @Tejaswee Lol I thought you are some new user .. I forgot abt your ID change.

Comment: @Rickross  This is the beauty of changing name....